# Peerjs, socket.io, Nodejs WEBRTC Chat App, Chat Video not showing up

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, webrtc, peerjs

I am currently building a Chat room with Video Call App with the help of Peerjs Server, Socket.io, Web RTC, and ExpressJS

Here is the room.ejs codes for the frontend of my app

which i define the script for socket.io and peerjs

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>videoChatApp</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c939d0e917.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>";
</script>
```

My Video Grid code block

```
<div class="main__left">
  <div class="videos__group">
    <div id="video-grid">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <div class="options__left">
      <div id="stopVideo" class="options__button">
        <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
      </div>
      <div id="muteButton" class="options__button">
        <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>
      </div>
      <div id="showChat" class="options__button">
        <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="options__right">
      <div id="inviteButton" class="options__button">
        <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For my script.js. I defined my Peerjs Server

```
var peer = new Peer({
   path: "/peerjs",
   host: "127.0.0.1",
   port: "9000",
});
```

Then I implement the Video and Chatting function

```
let myVideoStream;
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);

    peer.on("call", (call) => {
      call.answer(stream);
      const video = document.createElement("video");
      call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
      });
    });

    socket.on("user-connected", (userId) => {
      connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
    });
  });

const connectToNewUser = (userId, stream) => {
  const call = peer.call(userId, stream);
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
  });
};

peer.on("open", (id) => {
  socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_ID, id, user);
});

const addVideoStream = (video, stream) => {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    video.play();
    videoGrid.append(video);
  });
};

let text = document.querySelector("#chat_message");
let send = document.getElementById("send");
let messages = document.querySelector(".messages");

send.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (text.value.length !== 0) {
    socket.emit("message", text.value);
    text.value = "";
  }
});

text.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Enter" && text.value.length !== 0) {
    socket.emit("message", text.value);
    text.value = "";
  }
});
```

My server.js config

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require("peer");
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
  debug: true,
  allow_discovery: true,
});

app.use("/peerjs", peerServer);
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`);
});

app.get("/:room", (req, res) => {
  res.render("room", { roomId: req.params.room });
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("join-room", (roomId, userId, userName) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.to(roomId).emit("user-connected", userId);
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      io.to(roomId).emit("createMessage", message, userName);
    });
  });
});
```

The Chatting works as I can see messages between peers connection but The video connection doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me with this? I am very very appreciated

Comment: Bonus: for this project i temporary use the Local PeerJS server by running:  peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs --path /peerjs